# Difference between copying the object which was returned by value and moving it?

Tags: c++, optimization, move, move-semantics

I'm wondering if there is any sense to move return value of the function into `std::string` object instead of direct copying it?

"`ip_str`" is the object which should get the return value of "`getp1settings()`":

```
std::string ip_str = std::move(getp1settings());
```

Here below is the "getp1settings"'s implementation.

```
std::string SIGDManager::getp1settings() {

    DBAutoConnection connection;
    ...

    std::string p1_virtual;
    if (reader()) {
        reader >> p1_virtual;
    }

    ...

    return p1_virtual;
}
```

So, my question is what is the best way (in terms of performance) to get return value into "`ip_str`"?

1. `std::string ip_str = std::move(getp1settings());`
2. `std::string ip_str = getp1settings();`

Comment: `std::move` has no effect here. `std::move` does not move, it is merely a cast, and that case is superfluous in this case

Comment: My first recommendation is to not bother with the `std::move` to begin with. Build with optimizations, and benchmark/profile your program. This will likely not be on the top ten list of bottlenecks, and you should rarely do anything outside of the top five.

Comment: in C++ the best way in terms of performance is usually just write what you mean and leave the optimizations to compiler

Comment: with std::move you prevent RVO and therefore you're preventing the most valuable optimization

Comment: `std::move` on a function call expression is almost always wrong and always wrong if the function returns by-value. You should use `std::move` typically only on the name of a variable of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

A `std::string` can and will be moved from a r-value reference. You do not need `std::move` to cast to a r-value reference because `getp1settings()` is already one.

Comment: In fact, with `std::move` it becomes worse: Without it mandatory (since C++17) copy elision would have applied because `getp1settings()` is a prvalue of the same type as the variable. So no copy or move constructor would have been called. With `std::move` copy elision becomes impossible because now the initializer is an xvalue and a move constructor _must_ be called (as-if rule aside).

Comment: @user17732522 It's not a case for RVO, return value is named, so it's not a required optimisation. But it may interrupt NRVO possibility.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I am talking about the copy from the return value into `ip_str`, not from the local variable inside the function into the return value. Or to be technically correct in C++17: Because the function call expression is a prvalue and the parameter of `std::move` a reference, a temporary object is materialized for the call to `std::move`. Then `ip_str` is initialized from that temporary because `std::move` returns a reference to it, again without the possibility of any copy elision.

Comment: On the other hand when directly initializing from the function call prvalue, the variable is the result object for the initialization in the `return` operand and directly initialized by it.